# ValueError: Unknown string format dateparser python CSV

Tags: python, csv, graph, date-parsing

I am encountering some issues with Python's `dateutil.parser`.

I have a CSV file which I am to tasked to read and display the month.

A group may have `29 Jun 2017 1600` and some have "29 Jun 2017 1600 hrs", whenever the data has additional string such as hrs. it will display this error: `ValueError: Unknown string format`

Here is my code: `dt = dateutil.parser.parse(data.GetDataType(frequency))`

How do I remove the `hrs` or allow the program to be able to run smoothly?

Answer (score 0):

```
# full, working, python 3 solution
# modified to work on strings with or without "hrs"
# "$" in re.sub means hrs only matches at end of input string
# I hope you read this, because I can change this answer, but I cannot comment :-D

import re
from datetime import datetime

stringDateIn1 = "29 Jun 2017 1601"
stringDateIn2 = "29 Jun 2017 1602 hrs"

stringDateFixed1 = re.sub( " hrs$", "", stringDateIn1 )
stringDateFixed2 = re.sub( " hrs$", "", stringDateIn2 )

datetimeOut1 = datetime.strptime( stringDateFixed1, '%d %b %Y %H%M' )
datetimeOut2 = datetime.strptime( stringDateFixed2, '%d %b %Y %H%M' )

print( "date = " + str( datetimeOut1 ) )
print( "date = " + str( datetimeOut2 ) )
```

Comment: Some data has hrs while some doesn't. How do I ensure that it would run smoothly with or without the hrs? Thanks for the help!